# Monitor plugged into integrated graphics but use dedicated graphics for rendering games

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, games, pci-passthrough, gpu-passthrough

Is there a way to have the integrated graphics offload to the dedicated graphics card when I want to play a game? I want to leave the dedicated graphics card open for pass through to a Windows VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research it seems that PRIME is what I was looking for.
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PRIME
It allows the GPU to be inactive when a non GPU intensive program is running but only be active for GPU intensive programs.